# How to call swiftui struct from function

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui

The HomeView()struct is not able to call in function or in button action. How should i call the  HomeView() struct from another struct. While calling  HomeView() either in button action or function of LoginView() , am getting "Result of 'HomeView' initializer is unused"

```
struct LoginView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
    }
    func login()
    {
        HomeView() //Result of 'HomeView' initializer is unused "WARNING"
    }
}



struct LoginView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack
                {
                    Button(action: {
                        HomeView() //Result of 'HomeView' initializer is unused  "WARNING"
                    })
                    {
                        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Submit")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}



struct HomeView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
    }
    func submit()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: `HomeView()` is not a function, it is constructor of value, like `let view = HomeView()`

Comment: What do you mean by « call a struct » ? You don’t call structs. You create them, mutate them and copy them but I don’t know what you mean by calling a struct.

Comment: @DamiaanDufaux, i updated my post

Answer (score 1):

To present another view via button, please check below:

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State var showingHome = false
    var loginButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingHome.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Login")
            .foregroundColor(Color.init(.white))
            .font(.system(size: 14))
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.init(.systemOrange))
            .cornerRadius(4)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                loginButton.sheet(isPresented: $showingHome) {
                    HomeView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The user can dismiss if we present using sheet. i wanted to navigate between swiftui views

Comment: AnyView({ () -> AnyView in
             if user logged in {
                    return AnyView(HomeView())
                } else {
                    return AnyView(LoginView())
                }
      }

Comment: After a user logs in or already logged in, it will present the HomeView() otherwise it presents LoginView(). If this is what you wanted